# Exponential Distribution Life Time Problem

Tags: probability

Suppose we are dealing with a light bulb which burns through after a time $X$ distributed according to a negative exponential distribution:

$$P(X≤x)=1-e^{-λx}. \quad   0<λ<∞$$

We turn on the light bulb at time $t = 0$ and expect its burning through at time $t = X$. At an intermediate time $t = y$, before the burning through occurs, we would like to know the time remaining before the burning through.

Comment: Do you know the memorylessness of exponential distribution?

Comment: yes the memory less means it does not depend on the previous values

Comment: Then you can readily calculate $E(X \mid X > y)$ :)

Comment: you mean something like P(X>y) = 1-P(X<=y) = 1-(1-e^-λy) = e^-λy

Comment: $P(X > x + y \mid X > y) = P(X > x)$.

Comment: so how do we find the remaining time from point y untill the light burns ? I would appreciate if you give me a complete answer tnx :)

Comment: and so $\mathbb E[X \mid X \gt y] -y =\mathbb E[X-y \mid X \gt y] = \mathbb E[X \mid X \gt 0] =    \mathbb E[X] $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to find the distribution of $X|X>y$. To this end let's calculate $Pr(X<x|X>y)$:

$$Pr(X<x|X>y)={{Pr(X<x,X>y)}\over{Pr(X>y)}}$$$$={{Pr(X>y)-Pr(X>x)}\over{Pr(X>y)}}$$$$={{e^{-\lambda y}-e^{-\lambda x}}\over{e^{-\lambda y}}}$$$$=1-e^{-\lambda (x-y)}$$

therefore

$$f_{X|X>y}(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-y)}$$

Now we must calculate $E(X|X>y)$ as following:

$$E(X|X>y)=\int_{y}^{\infty} xf_{X|X>y}(x)dx$$$$=\int_{y}^{\infty} xf_{X|X>y}(x)dx$$$$=\int_{y}^{\infty} x\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-y)}dx=y+{1\over\lambda}$$

since we now the bulb not burnt before $X<y$ therefore the final answer is $E={1\over\lambda}$.